# Rails event_calendar week view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calendar, ruby-on-rails-4

This question exists on StackOverflow but it was not answered, just got suggestions...

Most people suggest to use full_calendar, because it is complete, but I couldn't get it work...Maybe because I'm on rails 4 and ruby 2, or maybe I don't have a compatible model, but event calendar seens to be complete and easy enough anyways...

I found on event_calendar ( lib / event_calendar / calendar_helper.rb ) these comments

```
#
# helper methods for working with a calendar week
#
```

by these comments I guess that is possible to use it in a week view. Anyone tried it ? If anyone have suggestions to work with week calendar on rails I would appreciate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone is looking for the answer, my suggestion is the calenderize gem!

https://rubygems.org/gems/calendarize